# Formula to Reference Sheet #7 Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Every week I create a new tab in my spreadsheet with the current Thursday's date in m.d.yy. format, and it's always in sheet position #7.

I'd like to put formulas in Sheet #6 (It never changes sheet position) that always references certain cells (ie A2, B2 etc) in Sheet #7 (The one with the current Thursday's date)

I've tried `='TEXT(5-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+TODAY(),"m.d.yy")'!B2` but it returns `#REF`

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas for me?

Comment: Use INDIRECT().

Comment: @ScottCraner What would go in the parenthesis?

Comment: All of it, with the proper use of `"` and `&` for proper concatenation.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you please answer the question and fix my formula? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show how you tried INDIRECT().  I am more a teach a person how, then give the answer.